# Why self-shadow aliasing occurs even when transformations of light clip space and camera clip space are same?

Tags: graphics, glsl, shadow, vulkan

I am trying to implement basic shadow mapping algorithm by vulkan and glsl. I try to figure out what reason causes self-shadow aliasing or self-occlusion. Obviously, self-occlusion is caused by mismatching between pixels of shadow map rasterized in light pass and camera pass.
There are two reasons causing the mismatching issue.

**1. Different rasterization caused by different transformation.**
[image]

The above picture depicts the rasterizations of same triangle in light pass and camera pass. Obviously, the triangle in camera pass occupies more pixels than in light pass. For simplicity, the blue four pixels of camera pass are roughly corresponding to one blue pixel of light pass. Thus the pixels of shadow map interpolated in camera pass are more than in light pass, causing the mismatching issue.

The number in blue square represents of the pixel's depth. As you can see, two of four blue pixels are occluded. Self-occulusion occurs.

**2. Float-arithmetic error**

Another reason is caused by numerical limits. Different float-arithemetic incur different round error, which causes the mismatching.

To verify my findings, I use one same clipe space transformation for light pass and camera pass, which should eliminate the first reason causing the mismatching. At this time, there should be no visible shadow. But there is still some self-shadow aliasing. I think it is caused by the second reason, which means **some different float-arithmetic exists in light pass and camera pass. I can not find the difference.**

### Here is my implmentation.

---

#### Light Pass

Light pass is a depth-only pass, it does not contain pixel shader. Vertex shader is as below:

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aVertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aVertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTextureCoord;

layout(binding = 0) uniform WorldMVP {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
};

layout(binding = 1) uniform uLightUbo{
    mat4 uLightView;
};

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * uLightView * model * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

#### Camera Pass

Camera pass is a normal color pass.

- Vertex Shader

```
#version 450

layout(binding = 0) uniform WorldMVP {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
};

layout(binding = 1) uniform LightUbo {
    mat4 uLightViewMatrix;
};

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aVertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aVertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTextureCoord;

layout(location = 0) out vec2 vTextureCoord;
layout(location = 1) out vec3 vFragPos;
layout(location = 2) out vec3 vNormal;
layout(location = 3) out vec4 vPositionFromLight;

const mat4 biasMat = mat4( 
    0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0 );

void main()
{
    vFragPos = aVertexPosition;
    vNormal = aVertexNormal;
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vPositionFromLight = proj * uLightViewMatrix * model * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vPositionFromLight = biasMat*vPositionFromLight;

    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
```

- Pixel Shader

```
#version 450

layout(push_constant) uniform uPushConstant {
    vec4 uLightPos;
    vec4 uCameraPos;
};

// material parameters
layout(binding = 2) uniform uMaterial {
    vec4 uKd;
    vec4 uKs;
    float uLightIntensity;
};

layout(binding = 3) uniform sampler2D uDiffuseTexSampler;
layout(binding = 4) uniform sampler2D uShadowMapTexSampler;    // From Light pass

layout(location = 0) in vec2 vTextureCoord;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vFragPos;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vNormal;
layout(location = 3) in vec4 vPositionFromLight;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

vec3 BlinnPhong()
{
    // ... blinn phong shading
}

void main()
{
    vec4 shadowCoord = vPositionFromLight / vPositionFromLight.w;
    float depthFromShadowMap = texture(uShadowMapTexSampler, shadowCoord.xy).r;
    float depthInLightSpace = shadowCoord.z;
    float visibility = 0.0;
    if(depthFromShadowMap >= (depthInLightSpace)){
        visibility = 1.0;
    }
    outColor = vec4(visibility * BlinnPhong(), 1.0);
}
```

In my test. `uLightView` or `uLightViewMatrix` is same as `WorldMVP.view`, which  ensures the transformations of light clip space and camera clip space are smae.

Comment: Why did you repeat the question? epeating questions to attract attention is not welcome.

Comment: @Rabbid76 My last question is seek to an intuitive explanation of self-occlusion. And this question is about float-arithmetic confusion of implmentation details of shadow mapping. I delete my last question and request a new session for well organization. I apologize for any inappropriate operations

Comment: [What is the reason of causing self-occlusion of shadow mapping algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69512091/what-is-the-reason-of-causing-self-occlusion-of-shadow-mapping-algorithm)